# Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined when testing for Enter Press

Tags: reactjs

I've read several post on here about this issue and still can't seem to fix this error. For context, I am working in a custom PopupWindow class that has a custom text_area box. This shouldn't be relative, except the typical properties for react input boxes are NOT available to be in the situation (i.e. onKeyPress). It has been replaced with onEnterKeyPress but essentially works the same.

Event Handler:

```
getKeyPress = evt => {
    let pressed = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    if(document.activeElement.tagName.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'textarea'){
        console.log("TRUE"); //Is returning TRUE
        if(pressed === 13){
            "<br  />"
        }
    }
}
```

Invoking Event Handler:

```
<PopupWindow onEnterKeyPress= {this.getKeyPress} >content here... </PopupWindow>
```

Comment: Please share a CodeSandbox or similar that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Ryan - Sorry but this is a very small part of a giant application. To do that I would have to encode several private company components

Comment: The CodeSandbox should just contain the simplest possible example that still reproduces your problem. I don't want to see the full code around this, but what you are showing right now isn't enough for anyone to help you. Creating the simplest possible example that still reproduces the problem should be your first debugging step regardless of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited information you're providing I think that in order to handle custom event you should register them with vanilla js in the component in one of the lifecycle methods. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener("customEvent", this.getKeyPress);
}
```

And of course unregister them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple keyPress event that shows keyCode. Theoretically, it should work the same when using custom events. Note that I am using **charCode** instead of **keyCode**:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          keyCode: null
        };
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleKeyPress = (event) => {
      this.setState({ keyCode: event.charCode })
    } 

    render() {
   
    return ( 
        <div>
          <textarea onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
          {this.state.keyCode && <span>KeyCode = {this.state.keyCode}</span>}
        </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script><div id="root" />
```